# configure apiMiddleware routes at runtime node.js

Tags: node.js, api

Is it possible to configure the **apiMiddleware** at runtime & route to respective class or api.

```
E.g  class standard = 1st
     section  = A

http://myschool.com/school/1/A/attendance 

var apiMiddleware = {

    school : {

        get : {

            //class id = 1
            1 : {  
                A : {
                   attendance : myschool.attendance
                }            

            }
        },
        post : {

        }
    }

}
```

As per the above example, I am retrieve the attendance sheet of 1st std of sectionA.

If i what attendance sheet of 1st std sectionB I don't want to rewrite the same code as

```
A : {
    attendance : myschool.attendance
  } 
B : {
    attendance : myschool.attendance
 }
```

till ..... 12th std .

Out there, expert's could have come across this problem & found solution also. Could be great to hear the suggestion on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use URL pattern with parameters:

```
http://myschool.com/:school/:class/:section/attendance
```

For example using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/:school/:class/:section', function(req,res,next){
   console.log(req.params);     
});
```

Here, the object `req.params` will have variable parts of the URL.